# Using Chat Application XMPPFramework Iam getting This Error

Tags: ios, iphone

Using Chat Application with XMPPFramework Iam getting This Error
 Message SendButton Action as given below, plz help me if any one have idea then tell me plz..............

```
- (IBAction)sendAction:(id)sender
            {
                if([_chatTextField.text length] > 0)
                {
                    NSString* po = getUser.ofUser;
                    bubbleTable.typingBubble = NSBubbleTypingTypeNobody;
                    NSBubbleData *messageBubble = [NSBubbleData dataWithText:_chatTextField.text date:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] type:BubbleTypeMine];
                    [bubbleData addObject:messageBubble];
                    [bubbleTable reloadData];
                    [bubbleTable scrollBubbleViewToBottomAnimated:YES];


                    [[QuoteMessageController SharedInstance] SendChatMessageTo:getUser.account withContent:_chatTextField.text toUserId:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)getUser.Id] andOFId:po andVerifyKey:chatMessageKey];
                }
```

Getting error in output as given bellow>>>>>>

```
        *** First throw call stack:
        (
            0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e18ff35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
            1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010da7bbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
            2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e18fe6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
            3   Foundation                          0x000000010ba211f8 -[NSString stringByAppendingString:] + 96
            4   SourceSage                          0x000000010ae0c939 +[SSWriteReadInDb writeQuotesTable:UserImageUrl:UserId:OfUser:] + 409
            5   SourceSage                          0x000000010adb8d56 -[QuoteMessageController SendChatMessageTo:withContent:toUserId:andOFId:andVerifyKey:] + 2454
            6   SourceSage                          0x000000010ad6ac30 -[SSChatViewController sendAction:] + 752
            7   UIKit                               0x000000010beb48be -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
            8   UIKit                               0x000000010bfbb410 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
            9   UIKit                               0x000000010bfba7df -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
            10  UIKit                               0x000000010befa308 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
            11  UIKit                               0x000000010befac33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
            12  UIKit                               0x000000010bec79b1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
            13  UIKit                               0x000000010bed4a7d _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370
            14  UIKit                               0x000000010beb0103 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961
            15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e0c5551 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
            16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e0bb41d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
            17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e0baa54 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
            18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e0ba486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
            19  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010fe7c9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
            20  UIKit                               0x000000010beb3420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
            21  SourceSage                          0x000000010ae02893 main + 115
            22  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ee2e145 start + 1
            23  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
        )
        libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
        (lldb)
```

Comment: From the stack trace it appears the error is occurring because of QuoteMessageController SendChatMessageTo:withContent:toUserId:andOFId:andVerifyKey:] which leads to the message [SSWriteReadInDb writeQuotesTable:UserImageUrl:UserId:OfUser:] where some string is probably not in the expected format. The bug could be due to undesired parameters passed. Also, though I am not very familiar with XMPPFramework but from my experience in this domain I would say these libraries may have some easy-to-occur bugs so if possible, don't hesitate to wander in them when situation demands.

Comment: ok i will check It,iam also very New to this XMPPFramework..

Comment: 2015-01-12 11:50:21.701 SourceSage[808:31203] user account(null)
2015-01-12 11:50:21.701 SourceSage[808:31203] chat Textfieldsdfd
2015-01-12 11:50:21.701 SourceSage[808:31203] po(null)
2015-01-12 11:50:21.701 SourceSage[808:31203] getUserID0
2015-01-12 11:50:21.702 SourceSage[808:31203] chat messgKey2365891
2015-01-12 11:53:27.318 SourceSage[808:31203] dbPath:/Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8454248E-7AE1-4B91-B706-3405E889DAB2/data/Containers/Data/Application/08CC88B9-E43D-4F3E-A56A-2717475B0AAD/Documents/Recipes/SourceSageDB.db
248E-7AE1-4B91-B706-

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this part of your stack trace:

```
2   CoreFoundation     0x000000010e18fe6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   Foundation         0x000000010ba211f8 -[NSString stringByAppendingString:] + 96
4   SourceSage         0x000000010ae0c939 +[SSWriteReadInDb writeQuotesTable:UserImageUrl:UserId:OfUser:] + 409
5   SourceSage         0x000000010adb8d56 -[QuoteMessageController SendChatMessageTo:withContent:toUserId:andOFId:andVerifyKey:] + 2454
6   SourceSage         0x000000010ad6ac30 -[SSChatViewController sendAction:] + 752
```

You'll see the exception is raised after a string is appended to a string. That is usually caused from appending `nil` to the string. By guess is that one of your `NSString` arguments that you're sending to the method below is `nil`.

```
[[QuoteMessageController SharedInstance] SendChatMessageTo:getUser.account
     withContent:_chatTextField.text 
     toUserId:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)getUser.Id] 
     andOFId:po
     andVerifyKey:chatMessageKey];
```

To find out if this is in fact the case, either set a breakpoint here and check all the values, or add in the following before you call this method:

```
NSLog(@"%@", getUser.account);
NSLog(@"%@", _chatTextField.text);
NSLog(@"%@", po);
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)getUser.Id]);
NSLog(@"%@", chatMessageKey);
```

I don't know what your parameters actually are, so remove the `NSLog`s for the variables that are not `NSString`. If one of these logs come back as `nil` or `null` (I forget what the console will output), then you found your issue. If it's an argument that you don't necessarily need, you should pass an empty `NSString` instead. I usually do this with a ternary. So assuming the culprit is `_chatTextField.text`, I would pass that argument as:

```
[[QuoteMessageController SharedInstance] SendChatMessageTo:getUser.account
     withContent:_chatTextField.text ?: @""
     toUserId:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)getUser.Id] 
     andOFId:po
     andVerifyKey:chatMessageKey];
```

Doing this basically says, if `_chatTextField.text` is true (which it will equate to if it is not `nill`), use that value, otherwise use `@""`

EDIT:

```
- (IBAction)sendAction:(id)sender
{
    if([_chatTextField.text length] > 0)
    {
        NSString* po = getUser.ofUser ?: @"";
        NSString *acct = getUser.account ?: @"";
        bubbleTable.typingBubble = NSBubbleTypingTypeNobody;
        NSBubbleData *messageBubble = [NSBubbleData dataWithText:_chatTextField.text date:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] type:BubbleTypeMine];
        [bubbleData addObject:messageBubble];
        [bubbleTable reloadData];
        [bubbleTable scrollBubbleViewToBottomAnimated:YES];


        [[QuoteMessageController SharedInstance] SendChatMessageTo:acct withContent:_chatTextField.text toUserId:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)getUser.Id] andOFId:po andVerifyKey:chatMessageKey];
}
```

Comment: 2015-01-12 11:38:58.035 SourceSage[673:20203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString stringByAppendingString:]: nil argument'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108073f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010795fbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108073e6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
 3   Foundation

Comment: 2015-01-12 11:50:21.701 SourceSage[808:31203] user account(null)
2015-01-12 11:50:21.701 SourceSage[808:31203] chat Textfieldsdfd
2015-01-12 11:50:21.701 SourceSage[808:31203] po(null)
2015-01-12 11:50:21.701 SourceSage[808:31203] getUserID0
2015-01-12 11:50:21.702 SourceSage[808:31203] chat messgKey2365891

Comment: @NayeemuddinShaik So there's your issue right there. `User account` and `po` are null. Those values cannot be null, that's what is causing your crash.

Comment: what i have to chainge now?can u tell me plz?

Comment: @NayeemuddinShaik See the edit I made to my post and use that code. Since I don't know exactly what you're doing, I can't advise any further. My guess is that user account shouldn't be empty, and maybe `po` as well. My solution should fix your crash, but you might have an issue that is more than just this. You're likely getting this exception because `XMPPFramework` expects that those fields have values.